# Where can I learn the proper way to answer professional emails?

Tags: keigo, email

I haven't found any good blogs or books explaining properly the way to start an email or to answer one.

For example, I received an email asking me about my availabilities for an interview:

> お世話になっております。
> Company name㈱総務人事部のContact nameでございます。
> この度--会社--の人事役員面接を設定させて頂きたくご連絡致しました。
> 1/10以降でご都合の良い日時を2～3候補頂けますでしょうか。
> ご連絡お待ちしております。
> よろしくお願い致します。

How should I answer? I'd like to say any day any time is fine from 1/10 with a preference as soon as possible (next 2-3 days).

I'd also like to stay natural without using very complicated sentences someone with my Japanese level wouldn't say.

> company name株式会社 総務人事部
> contact name様へ、
>
> お世話になっております。
> my nameでございます。(Do I need to tell who I am since they contacted me first?)
> ご連絡ありがとうございました。
>
> 面接については、1/10の次の２－３営業日でも宜しいでしょうか。
> 何時でも大丈夫です。
>
> よろしくお願い致します。

If you have some references where I could learn that, please let me know.

Comment: こんな感じで書いてみたら・・　https://employment.en-japan.com/tenshoku-daijiten/42022/#i-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [one link](https://business-mail.jp/example). If you type in ビジネスメール into a search engine you should have a plethora of resources.

Some pointers:
1. You don't need 「へ、」after the contact name (unless you're mirroring how they addressed you).
2. You should always include your name prominently, so as to not necessitate their having to search for it and to alleviate any potential for confusion.
3. I would suggest that instead of 「1/10の次の２－３営業日…」, that you specified from and to dates (〇月〇日～〇月〇日の間）.